# How to make image responsive in columns grid with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an 8 columns grid, in which I want to distribute content, text and an image, as follows:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-8 gap-4">
  <div className="col-start-2 col-end-5">
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad
      tempora perferendis tenetur quia vitae blanditiis, excepturi quo
      inventore. Molestias cum eaque natus sequi nisi ea, dolor atque
      at? Fuga ipsa unde consectetur nobis consequatur tempore
      asperiores, quos alias similique, rerum nemo illo qui quidem
      accusantium molestiae voluptates deleniti praesentium sint?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum
      obcaecati accusamus quam eius doloremque. Error dignissimos modi
      eveniet at. Voluptate, sed ea. Eius veniam odit voluptatem error
      commodi amet repudiandae ut ab quos. Reiciendis officia placeat
      harum nulla obcaecati magni accusantium dolorem architecto ullam,
      ratione cumque distinctio consectetur esse deleniti.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div className="col-start-6 col-end-8">
    <img alt="dummy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The code above produces this result on a 1200px screen:

[image]

And this one on an 800px screen:

[image]

How can I have the image responsive, and get its height adapt to the text content on the left, so the vertical side of the image always takes the height of the text regardless of screen-size?

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/6Jnn6ewZbo)

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox ? With your code, the image is below text

Comment: If you are on the TailwindCSS playground you may need to replace `className` with `class`

Comment: sorry i used a sandbox with old tailwind version. I try and come for an update

Comment: I added a sandbox link at the end of my question

Comment: Is flexbox an option or only grid ?

Comment: Flexbox is fine too!

Comment: You want the image to be the size of text content with fixed width ! right ?

Comment: Yes. basically to resize so it occupies the height of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `flex` this would be simplest of all in my opinion:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="mr-8 w-8/12">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora perferendis tenetur quia vitae blanditiis, excepturi quo inventore. Molestias cum eaque natus sequi nisi ea, dolor atque at? Fuga ipsa unde consectetur nobis consequatur tempore asperiores, quos alias similique, rerum nemo illo qui quidem accusantium molestiae voluptates deleniti praesentium sint?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum obcaecati accusamus quam eius doloremque. Error dignissimos modi eveniet at. Voluptate, sed ea. Eius veniam odit voluptatem error commodi amet repudiandae ut ab quos. Reiciendis officia placeat harum nulla obcaecati magni accusantium dolorem architecto ullam, ratione cumque distinctio consectetur esse deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w-4/12 bg-cover bg-center" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x500)"></div>
</div>
```

[tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/sUb521dolE)

Note: Width uses standard `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12` columns there is no 8 columns

Comment: I like this one not mixing flex and grid, thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear it !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest(I think) would just be to set the second column to have a background image instead of an image inside, such as:

```
    <div class="grid grid-cols-8 gap-4">
     <div class="col-start-2 col-end-5">
      <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora perferendis tenetur quia vitae blanditiis,
      excepturi quo inventore. Molestias cum eaque natus sequi nisi ea, dolor atque at? Fuga ipsa unde consectetur nobis
      consequatur tempore asperiores, quos alias similique, rerum nemo illo qui quidem accusantium molestiae voluptates
      deleniti praesentium sint? </p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum obcaecati accusamus quam eius doloremque. Error
      dignissimos modi eveniet at. Voluptate, sed ea. Eius veniam odit voluptatem error commodi amet repudiandae ut ab
      quos. Reiciendis officia placeat harum nulla obcaecati magni accusantium dolorem architecto ullam, ratione cumque
      distinctio consectetur esse deleniti. </p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-start-6 col-end-8 bg-center bg-cover" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x500)"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the aspect-ratio of the image then you can always use flex.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-8 gap-4">
      <div class="col-start-2 col-end-5">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora perferendis tenetur quia vitae blanditiis, excepturi quo inventore. Molestias cum eaque natus sequi nisi ea, dolor atque at? Fuga ipsa unde consectetur nobis consequatur tempore asperiores, quos alias similique, rerum nemo illo qui quidem accusantium molestiae voluptates deleniti praesentium sint?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum obcaecati accusamus quam eius doloremque. Error dignissimos modi eveniet at. Voluptate, sed ea. Eius veniam odit voluptatem error commodi amet repudiandae ut ab quos. Reiciendis officia placeat harum nulla obcaecati magni accusantium dolorem architecto ullam, ratione cumque distinctio consectetur esse deleniti.</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="flex col-start-6 col-end-8">
        <img alt="dummy" className="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x500" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or if you do care about the aspect-ratio and don't care if the image gets cropped then you can set it as a background in the second div.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-8 gap-4">
      <div class="col-start-2 col-end-5">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora perferendis tenetur quia vitae blanditiis, excepturi quo inventore. Molestias cum eaque natus sequi nisi ea, dolor atque at? Fuga ipsa unde consectetur nobis consequatur tempore asperiores, quos alias similique, rerum nemo illo qui quidem accusantium molestiae voluptates deleniti praesentium sint?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum obcaecati accusamus quam eius doloremque. Error dignissimos modi eveniet at. Voluptate, sed ea. Eius veniam odit voluptatem error commodi amet repudiandae ut ab quos. Reiciendis officia placeat harum nulla obcaecati magni accusantium dolorem architecto ullam, ratione cumque distinctio consectetur esse deleniti.</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="flex col-start-6 col-end-8" style="background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x500)">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stretch the image to cover whole parent and then use [object-fit](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit) to adjust clipping:

```
<img class="h-full w-full object-cover">
```

This will crop sides and show largest possible area, `object-contain` will show full image. No `object-*` or `object-fill` will deform it.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-8 gap-4">
  <div class="col-start-2 col-end-5">
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora perferendis tenetur quia vitae blanditiis, excepturi quo inventore. Molestias cum eaque natus sequi nisi ea, dolor atque at? Fuga ipsa unde consectetur nobis consequatur tempore asperiores,
      quos alias similique, rerum nemo illo qui quidem accusantium molestiae voluptates deleniti praesentium sint?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum obcaecati accusamus quam eius doloremque. Error dignissimos modi eveniet at. Voluptate, sed ea. Eius veniam odit voluptatem error commodi amet repudiandae ut ab quos. Reiciendis officia
      placeat harum nulla obcaecati magni accusantium dolorem architecto ullam, ratione cumque distinctio consectetur esse deleniti.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="relative col-start-6 col-end-8">
    <img class="absolute h-full w-full object-cover" alt="dummy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, because having an <img> tag rather than a background I can treat it as a block element to stack them in small screens rather than having them side by side!